# How to remove class from post after 24 hours from created post?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have in table as you all know column **created_at** , so I want to say in jQuery after create post in 24 hours just remove class from the post

this is the code of created_at in hidden div :

```
 <div style="display:none">
    <div id="time_show" aria-label="{{ $userMsg->created_at }}"></div>
</div>
```

and this is the code of jquery ( I know this not right way to create what I want , so bear with me ) the code as the getting to me :(

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ 

            $('.arrow_box').removeClass('class');
        }, 350000);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you do the heavy lifting in Laravel with Carbon:

```
<div id="time_display" style="display:none">
    <div id="time_show" data-time-check="{{ $userMsg->created_at->gt(Carbon::now()->subDays(1)) }}"></div>
</div>
// Could be lt() or gt(), I wasn't sure which you wanted, but just play with it :)
```

Then, if the page loads and the msg is over 24 hours old (sub one day), then remove the class in jQuery:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var $div = $("#time_display");
      var check = $("#time_show").data('time-check');
      if(check){
         $div.removeClass('class');
      }
   }
</script>
```

Not exact code, but should get you where you want to go.

Comment: What doesn't run?  It doesn't trigger?  It has an error?  Did you try changing to `lt()` instead of `gt()`?  What did you do to troubleshoot the issue?  Are the values coming from the controller correct?  This code is a good example of how to do this, but you will need to craft it for your own program; you may have some specific elements that need changes based on *something else* in your code.  You will need to work through it yourself, but this answer is correct for the question.